# unnecessary characters getting added in URL when using rails link_to helper anchor tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm trying to add `#xyz` to a link which is generated using rails `link_to` helper.

Following is my code:

```
<%= link_to('', edit_notification_path(:id => item.id,:type =>"requester_template", 
:notification_type => @notification_type,:anchor => "#xyz"), 
:class => 'icon-pencil-3' ) %>
```

But the generated URL looks like

```
email_notifications/3/edit/requester_template?notification_type=ticket#%23es
```

That is there is an extra %23 that gets added with the anchor.

What am I doing wrong here ? ( Rails beginner here )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `:anchor => "#xyz"`to `:anchor => "xyz"`. The option `:anchor` already includes the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= link_to('', edit_notification_path(id: item.id,type: "requester_template", 
notification_type: @notification_type,anchor: "xyz"), 
class: 'icon-pencil-3' ) %>
```